# Unable to execute .jsp files getting an error java.lang.classNotFoundException:com.mysql.jdbc.driver

Tags: mysql, jsp

I tried to execute a wab page with the help of JSP & mysql as a database. After execution of first web pages it never shows the credential which is eneterd in the login page. In tomcat logs it gives the error of *`"java.lang.classNotFoundException:com.mysql.jdbc.driver"`*

Download a mysqlconnector into the below path: *`"D:\mohit\mysql-connector-java-5.1.23"`*

I have entered a CLASS PATH in system *Environmental variables* as *`D:\mohit\mysql-connector-java-5.1.23\mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar`*

Local system java is installed at *`C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_17`*

Please let me know how can I overcome from this problem?

Comment: Which IDE you are using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to have a JAR file somewhere containing `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` class (so called JDBC driver). This JAR needs to be visible in Tomcat. So, I would suggest to place mysql-jdbc.jar at physical location to `/WEB-INF/lib` directory of your project.

Many times `ClassNotFoundException` occurs if jar is not at physical location.  Do not play with Classpath if you are not sure. It is always suggested to put external "Jars" under `/WEB-INF/lib` directory and restart Tomcat, It takes care the rest.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj: It is suggested to accept the helpful answer. Read more http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation

Answer (score 1):

Put the mysql-connector jar inside `tomcat/lib/ext` folder and restart tomcat.

Comment: Sir i have already done the same process but still not having the permanent solution for it

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are running the application on server from eclipse itself, the jar is not getting pushed to server. Try placing the jar file in WEB-INF/lib folder

Comment: the page i was designed its not execute on server ..its basically execute on local pc with the help of jsp and mysql and apache tomcat server

Comment: "not execute on server" ? And you mentioned apache tomcat server

Comment: This is a simple web page for which i am trying to track record for current incident which are running in a single project..i m using HTML+JSP+MYSQL+TOMCAT for online execution of this web refrence on a local PC..